# Target the child element with styled-components with specificity level 1

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

The scenario is I have a component i.e. `<BrandLogo />` which is styled with the underlying `<a>` element. The component also has an `img` element as a child. Is there a way to create styles for child element with the help of `styled-components` that has specificity level 1.

I know I can directly target the child element with `styled-components`.

**Approach 1:**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const BrandLogo = styled.a`
    color: #1a1c1c;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top; 
    img {
    display:block;
    }
`;

const App = () => {

    return (<div style={{backgroundColor: '#e6e6e6'}}>
        <BrandLogo href="/">
            <img src="https://dcstatic.com/images/brandcrowd/logos/brandcrowd-logo-5d59400c52.svg" alt="BrandCrowd"/>
        </BrandLogo>
    </div>)
};

export default App;
```

The following markup will be generate:

```
<div style="background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);">
        <a class="sc-bdVaJa gdDbnn" href="/"><img alt="BrandCrowd" src="https://dcstatic.com/images/brandcrowd/logos/brandcrowd-logo-5d59400c52.svg"></a>
    </div>
```

But the specificity of the `img` element is level 2.

```
.gdDbnn img {
    display: block;
}
```

**Approach 2:**

Create the `img` element as a styled component but now it's considered as a component. Yes this approach will create style with specificity level 1.

But Is there any other approach to style child components with specificity level 1.

Comment: Styled component is a just css, how would you specifiy `img` as level1 if not the second option with css?

Comment: @DennisVash  yes second option genrate img specificity with level 1 but I am just asking is there any alternative to target child elements.